# What kind of numerical optimization approach can I use to solve the following problem?

Tags: reference-request, numerical-optimization

I have a non linear problem to solve which is something like (just to give a rough idea)

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\min \sum_{k=1}^{n} z_k^2 \\
\text{s.t.} \\
\lVert p_i - p_j \rVert_2^2 = \text{constant}_{ij} \\
x_iy_j - y_ix_j \geq 0
\end{array}
$$

here $p_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i)$, I'm reading through a numerical optimization book to try at least to classify the problem, but it seems to me I can only use some SQP solver, is there anything else you can suggest?

I'm pretty sure this problem doesn't have a unique solution, but I have the feeling these solution would be somehow equivalent, so finding a local minimum should be fine.

Comment: $\lVert p_i - p_j \rVert_2^2 = \text{constant}$ looks restrictive: in $3$ dimensions, you cannot have more than the four points of a tetrahedron.

Comment: Changed, but anyway what I meant is "distance preserving among neighbors"

Comment: If $x_i y_j \geq x_j y_i$ needs to hold for every pair $(i,j)$, then you necessarily have $x_iy_j = x_jy_i$ for every such pair. Another observation is that if $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$, $i = 1,\cdots,n$, is a solution, then so is $(-x_i,-y_i,\pm z_i)$. These may be helpful in characterizing the multiplicity of solutions. With regards to solvers, you can also try interior point solvers such as IPOPT.